# Windows Phone TimePicker change pop up color

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

How can I set the colours on the pop up Windows from the TimePicker on WP7? By editing the style I can set the colors of the picker but not of the following window. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here under the heading "Customizing the Full Screen Picker Page":

[WP7 DatePicker and TimePicker in depth](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization)